# Word-like program with tabbed documents

Tags: windows, word-processor

Are there any Word-like programs with tabbed documents? Similar to excel's project tabs but with text documents.

- Windows 10
- Free preferred
- Files able to be exported into a Word compatible doc is preferred

Comment: It looks like there is a paid option for Word through an add-on: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/418-enable-word-tabbed-documents.html